# Handling quoted expressions in Z3

Tags: z3, substitution

I'm currently working with Z3's `unsat_core` functionality in the context of a model checking class at university.

The issues arises when trying to work with the assumptions that Z3 provides me with in the core:

E.g.:

```
z3::expr_vector unsat_core = exp_solver.unsat_core();
for(auto const c : unsat_core) {
  DEBUG << "\n" << c;
}
```

prints a list containing, for example, such an expression:

```
|(let ((a!1 (bvnot (ite (= current_state_V0 ((_ zero_extend 1) #b11)) #b1 #b0))))
 (let ((a!2 (bvnot (bvand a!1 (bvnot ((_ extract 2 2) current_state_V0))))))
 (let ((a!3 (bvor a!2
                 (ite (= next_state_V0 (bvadd current_state_V0 #b001)) #b1 #b0)
                 (bvnot #b1))))
  (= a!3 #b1))))|
```

We add and track expressions via this wrapper:

```
void add_and_track(z3::solver& s, z3::expr_vector const &v)
{
  check_context(s, v);
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
  {
    s.add(v[i], v[i].to_string().c_str());
  }
}
```

I now need to encode these assumptions with my primed variables and I intend to use `z3::expr::substitute` for that, but that does not seem to work.

```
DEBUG << unsat_core[0];
z3::expr foo = unsat_core[0].substitute(V0, V1);
DEBUG << unsat_core[0];
DEBUG << foo;
```

all `DEBUG` calls print out the exact same (quoted) expression from above.

`V0` and `V1` are `z3::expr_vector`s containing the variables and the primed variables, and `DEBUG` is a wrapper around `std::cout`.

My best guess is that these expressions are 'quoted'  [https://www.lri.fr/~conchon/TER/2013/2/SMTLIB2.pdf#page=22](https://www.lri.fr/%7Econchon/TER/2013/2/SMTLIB2.pdf#page=22) Is this correct?

What I would like to achieve is either to be able to substitute or the extract the expression that is, as I am guessing, quoted.

Comment: Indeed, any symbol that's wrapped in bar's (i.e., '|') is a quoted symbol. But I don't think that's your problem here. You should post a minimal-reproducible-example so it can be debugged; see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'll give that a try, thanks. I'm fairly new to the c++-API and I've only worked with toy examples for z3py so far. The intend of my question was to find out whether there is a way to `get_expr_from_quoted()`, I was looking for such a method in the API. Will post an MWE as soon as I can.

Comment: You should not be needing `get_expr_from_quoted` at all. What's internally stored should be a valid expression; quoting is just a mere artifact of how things are printed  to stdout or to a file. Something else must be wrong in your code such that the substitution is not happening properly for some other reason.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, it did help a lot to get onto the right track. My problem turned out to be twofold: (1) I did not understand how the tracking of the unsat core works, I was expecting it to contain all the _tracked expressions_ that I have added to the core via the c++ wrappers that eventually call `Z3_solver_assert_and_track()`, but instead it pushed the `bool_const`s that flag these expressions that have been used to show UNSAT to the core.

Comment: (2) Our tutor could then help us out to solve the issue: He never intended for us to use the tracking but to pass the _interesting_ expressions directly via `check(expr_vector ...)`. That means that there is a definite distinction between these two approaches. I will add that information to the question and maybe a clarification about how to use the `unsat_core` as an answer, as that was where the problem arose. Is there some more documentation, other than the three examples from the github repository?